# IUrlHelper.ActionLink Removing Part of Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have two environments, one having a sub-domain of **dev-quote** and one with **live-quote**. The dev-quote one works as intended as it is generating a absolute URL fine with the sub-domain intact.

However, the live-quote on seems to be generating a URL of "quote.sitenamehere.com" rather than the "live-quote.sitenamehere.com".

I am curious to whether anyone else has had this issue or whether it could be the way the infrastructure has been created which sadly none of the development team has had any involvement in.

In terms of code used to generate the link, all it consists of is the following:

`Url.ActionLink(nameof(ActionName))`

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue. Did you check `appsettings.json` for the various environments?

Comment: Yeah, checked there and nothing along the lines of a URL is ever used, it only seems to be for the live environment, going to do some digging tomorrow and see if I can do something to force it to use it

Comment: What does Httpcontext.Request.Host return?